# How to keep a UIBarButtonItem centered when adding/removing other UIBarbuttons?

Tags: ios, center, uibarbuttonitem, space

I have a UIToolbar with 3 UIBarButtonItems and a flexible space on either side. I'm using this to navigate through an array while using the center UIBarButtonItem as a title.

The situation looks like this:

```
<--> [<] [Title] [>] <-->
```

When at the beginning of the array, I'd like to remove the [<] button and vice versa when reaching the end of the array for the [>] button.

How do I keep the [Title] button centered so that it doesn't move when one of the other UIBarButtons gets removed/added?

Notes:

- I already know how to add/remove buttons programmatically in a toolbar
- The problem is that every time, it centers around both remaining UIBarbuttons, where I need it to center on just the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the [>] or [<] buttons with a fixed width spacer when you reach the end/beginning of the pages.

Comment: Hah! I was focusing too much on hiding dummy buttons when this is exactly where you want to use the fixed spacers! I've never had any use for those before which is why I never thought of them. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes its the little things that you've been staring at for hours and would have never seen.